# Why does Gridlayout move view out of sight at a certain point

Tags: java, android

I played around with GridView in Android a bit and there was something strange I noticed, that I could not explain.
In my XML I have an ImageView and underneath a GridView with 4 buttons:

https://s17.directupload.net/images/191020/kho7sds4.png

The code of the XML looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:columnCount="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:rowCount="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="3"/>

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now when I increase the size of the picture (height:550dp), it looks like this:

https://s17.directupload.net/images/191020/qarbb8g8.png

I guess that the buttons don't have place anymore to display their text correctly, but why would Android then display the GridLayout that way? Is there any way to make this View "failsafe"?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.You should change the button height property to zero then they would be scale to fit into your grid view.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:columnCount="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:rowCount="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="3"/>

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Hadi, thank you for your answer. But do you know, why this problem occurs?

Comment: it's because you set the height of your button to wrap_content and because of this they can not change their height accordingly.